# How do I make a date object searchable in a range

Tags: ruby, date, search, methods, formatting

I have an array of hashes in a Ruby file that contain dates and I need to be able to search and display the hashes using Ruby as desired with a FROM and a TO date. How can I go about this? It doesn't appear so far that I can leave the dates in date format to search for them. Any suggestions?

Here is what I've tried so far for formatting prior to searching:

```
def reporting_display
  while true
    puts "Please enter a date range (yyyy-mm-dd) FROM and TO"
    puts "FROM:"
    get_from = gets.chomp
    if validate_date(get_from)
      @from = Date.parse(get_from)
      puts "TO:"
      get_to = gets.chomp
      if validate_date(get_to)
        @to = Date.parse(get_to)
        puts "Please wait"
        break
      else
        puts "Invalid input" #may be able to remove this and rely on if from's Invalid input
      end
    else
      puts "Invalid input"
    end
  end

  @from
  @to
end
```

TO QUERY the data I tried:

```
def query_sales_csv
  CSV.foreach('sales_data.csv', headers: true) do |row|
    @sales_from_csv << row
  end
  @sales_from_csv
  @sales_from_csv.each do |order|
    if [@from..@to].include?(order[:date])
      puts "Date: #{order[:date]} - Units Sold: #{order[:units_sold]} - Gross Profit: $#{order[:gross_profit]} - COGS: $#{order[:cogs]} - Net Profit: $#{order[:net_profit]}"
    else
      puts "Error: Invalid Range"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: How does the hash looks like..you need to provide some raw data which you have been trying with

Comment: @ CDub and @Bijendra I added the code I was working with. If you need anything else please let me know, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your hash looks something like this

```
dates = [{:name =>"jan", :val => Date.new(2013, 1, 1)}, {:name => "feb", :val => Date.new(2013, 2, 1)}, {:name => "mar", :val => Date.new(2013, 3, 1)}]
```

then the following find_all will work

```
earliest = Date.new(2013, 1, 15)
latest = Date.new(2013, 3, 15)
dates.find_all{|h| h[:val] >= earliest and h[:val] <= latest}
```

UPDATED: now that there is code, the line

```
 if [@from..@to].include?(order[:date])
```

is wrong, it should be

```
 if (@from..@to).include?(order[:date])
```

to see why use irb to look at

```
[Date.new(2013, 1, 1)..Date.new(2013, 1, 2)].class # Array
[Date.new(2013, 1, 1)..Date.new(2013, 1, 2)][0].class # Range
```

vs

```
(Date.new(2013, 1, 1)..Date.new(2013, 1, 2)).class # Range
```

Your code was checking the Array to see if it includes the date. It does not, it contains just a single element, the range. The new code is range of dates.